# Is there any way to add VPN information using appium to devices in aws devicefarm devicepool?

Tags: java, appium, appium-android, aws-device-farm

I want to automate an android application using Appium, Java and TestNG on aws device-farm.
However, VPN information must be added to access this application.

When I used remote control on AWS device-farm, I was able to set VPN information on the device and access the application, but when I want to create a device pool and run my automation tests on these devices I couldnt any way to set VPN information to all devices in aws device-pool.

So, is there a way to set the VPN information automatically via device-farm or appium?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by replacing the
`appium_server_url` from:

```
localhost:4723
```

to

```
127.0.0.1
```

In other words, instead of `localhost`, use an IP address, e.g. `127.0.0.1`